# find multiple columns values in the postures database table

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Table students(id,country_code,student_name) values 
(10,12,india),(12,12,india),(16,12,india),(19,13,china),(10,19,chile)
Requirement is to list multiple occurred "student_name" (corresponding id should be in the result) ?????
expected result:
(10,india)
(12,india)
(16,india)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query like this,

```
select * students
where student_name in (
select student_name from students group by student_name having 
count(student_name) > 1)
```